# why is this giving me an error, python noughts and crosses game

Tags: python

I am getting an error with the first function that I have

```
def print():
    list = [[" ","1","2","3"],["1","-","-","-"],["2","-","-","-"],["3","-","-","-"]]
    for item in list:
        print(" ".join(item))

def gorow():
    userrow = input("row")
    return int(userrow)

def gocolumn():
    usercolumn = input("column")
    return int(usercolumn)

print()

x = list[gorow()][gocolumn()]

print()
```

Comment: And what is that error?  Could you post the traceback?

Comment: @Cyber Also `print` as the name of the function

Answer (score 1):

Do not use type names as variables names. Change your variable `list` so it does not conflict with a typename.

And since you named your function `print`, Python will attempt to recursively call your `print` function, instead of the actual Python `print` function. I'm assuming it is then throwing a `TypeError` because your `print` function does not take any arguments.

Comment: Nitpick - `list` isn't a `keyword` :)

Comment: You're not a keyword!! Okay I'll change it :)

Answer (score 1):

You used a function is already exist. Dont use def print(). Print is already exist. Change the name

Answer (score 0):

Rename function print to myprint

```
def print():
```

to

```
def myprint():
```

then call it

```
myprint()
```